# How do I open uploaded files in a modal dialog when the corresponding button in the grid is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, modal-dialog

When I click the corresponding button for each row, the latest uploaded pdf file is shown in the iframe for all the other button clicks. The Iframe content does not seem to be refreshed. Here is my code:

```
<a  onclick="opendoc(id)" data-id="<?php echo $value["doc_id"]; ?>"class="button blue" id="<?php echo $value["doc_id"]; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">View File</h4> 
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
        <iframe src="download.php?mode=view&id=<?php echo $value["document"];?>" id="myframe" style="border:5px solid grey;" width="800" height="600"></iframe>
</div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
function opendoc(id)
  {
  var omyFrame = document.getElementById("myframe");

omyFrame.style.display="block";
alert(id);

  }
```

and for showing file to iframe,
download.php is as follows

```
<?php
    $file = './uploads/'.$_GET['id'];
    $title=$_GET['id'];





    header("Pragma: public");
   // header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$title);
    //header('Content-disposition: inline');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $file . '"');
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.word');
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
      header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    //header('Content-type: text/plain');
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');   
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

    ob_clean();
    flush();


        readfile($file);

    ?>
```

Comment: Can you post your full loop code as well?

Comment: Is there anything to be added more in javascript?